# how to tie mssql table on jqgrid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, jqgrid

I want to make a jqgrid and i want to put there 2 tables from mssql database.
I Made a .php but didn't work, can someone watch a sec why dosen't work?
I'm neewbie on this thing..

Code>

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "test"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

// Declare the SQL query for Database
$query = "Select [Column 1]";
$query = "From table_test1";

//Execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

//Display the results
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))


//Close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

and the jqgrid code>

```
<html>
<head>
    <title id='Description'>Expedio Weekly Tickets</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="Style/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css"/>    
    <script  type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (){

            $("#grid").jqGrid({ 
            data: mydata, 
            datatype: 'local',
            width: 1320,
            colNames: ["A", "B", "C"],
            colModel:
                     [
            {name: 'A', index: 'A', key: true, width:10},
            {name: 'B', index: 'B', width:20},
            {name: 'C', index: 'C', width:40}
                     ],
            pager: '#pager', 
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Test"
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I Get this error>>

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Connect.php on line 8

Comment: Are you sure that you have switched on the extension for mssql?

Answer (score 0):

- Are you running a MySQL server or Microsoft sql server? Else ever mssql_[command] should be mysql_[command].
- Your query string get's overwritten in the line after the string is declared. it should:
  $query = "Select column_name ";
  $query .= "From table_test1";
  This would make $query equal to "Select column_name From table_test".
- Does table_test1 exist in your database and are the use credentials to logon correct?
- Your while loop does loop anything (see: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) for an example.
- The php code doesn't output anything as JSON which should be necessary for JQGrid to load the data from your database.
- The jqgrid only displays example data.

I suggest try to read some more about php and javascript before deep-diving into coding.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably caused because of missing PHP extension for communication with MSSQL. Read how to install the mssql extension in the php manual here:

**http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php** - especially sections *requirements* and *installation*

Answer (score 0):

```
Usee the Adodb class to connect to sqlserver 2008:
The find here:

http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Example Usage:
include ('adodb / adodb.inc.php ");
$ Conn = & ADONewConnection (odbc_mssql);
/ * Create a connection object to SQL Server * /
$ Data = "Driver = {SQL Server}; Server = 192.168.1.28; Database = master;"
/ * We define our DSN * /
$ Connection-> Connect ($ data, 'db_user', 'pass_dbuser');
/ * Make the connection to the corresponding parameters * /
$ Sql ​​= "SELECT count (*) as count FROM TABLEBD";
/ * SQL Reference is made to know how many records are displayed * /
$ Result = & $ conn-> Execute ($ sql);
if (! $ result)
    print $ conn-> ErrorMsg ();
// Declare an if in case your query has not been executed well, to show us the error
else {
    if ($ result-> EOF) {$ count = $ result-> fields [0];}
    // Echo "The number of records is:" $ count;.

}
/ * We close objects, this step is optional, but optimized our code * /
$ Result-> Close ();
$ Connection-> Close ();

Good Look

fastdid
```